# Is it possible to disable spawning of specific vehicles?

Tags: prison-architect

Through modding or otherwise, is it possible to disable the spawning of specific vehicles, i.e. hearses when prisoners die?

Comment: Just curious, but why would you want corpses all over your prison?

Comment: Let's just say that I have...other plans for them.